# Linux - Creating multiple folders from a text file

Tags: linux, scripting

```
   #!/bin/bash
   IFS='
   '
   for _dir in $(cat "$1 usernames.lnk"); do
   mkdir "$_dir Windows"
   done
```

I am having trouble with this script, It has to create a folder within the Windows folder of each name that is listed in the usernames.lnk text file, but everytime I try and run the script it states "usernames.lnk" directory could not be found. The script and the username file and the Windows folder are all in the same folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A few obvious things. 1. `$1` will be replaced with the first argument of the script, or nothing if there are no arguments. 2. `cat "foo bar"` will look for the file that has a space in its name. So will `cat " bar"`. You probably want `usernames.lnk` or perhaps `"$1/usernames.lnk"`. 3. `mkdir "foo bar"` will try to create a directory with a space in its name. You probably want `"Windows/$_dir"`.

Answer (score 4):

This will read each line of the file `usernames.lnk` and create a directory under the directory `Windows` (relative path).

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    mkdir "Windows/$line"
done < usernames.lnk
```

Comment: You should have `"$link"` in double quotes, or this will break if the file contains a file name with spaces or other shell special characters. See also `read -r` and the FAQ for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This way should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat usernames.lnk`;
do mkdir "Windows/$i";
done
```